# IF statement with unreacheable else

Tags: java, if-statement

Why is the method shown below compiled and run by Java?

```
public static void testIf(int v){
   if (v < 10)   
      
   if (v >20 )  
     System.out.println(" 20 IF");
   else        
     System.out.println(" 20 ELSE");

   else        
     System.out.println("10 Else");
}
```

- Normally every IF should be linked with the closest ELSE, why the last else is not a dangling ELSE? Moreover with what IF is linked.
- The last ELSE is not reachable, why it's allowed?

Comment: Please consider the space in between the first two if statements.

Comment: "The last ELSE is not reachable, why it's allowed" what if `v>=10`?

Comment: "closest" else isn't a thing. It's the `{}`, or lack thereof which determines the grouping if-else

Comment: It's `"  20 IF"` which is actually unreachable. A number can't be both less than 10 and greater than 20.

Comment: As this code style confuses you (and most other people as well), use curly braces. Always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Else matching If

If you use a formatter, it will show which if's and else's are matched:

```
public static void testIf(int v) {
    if (v < 10)

        if (v > 20)
            System.out.println(" 20 IF");
        else
            System.out.println(" 20 ELSE");

    else
        System.out.println("10 Else");
}
```

Your assumption that 'Normally every IF should be linked with the closest ELSE' is not entirely true. If you don't use curly brackets, the body of the if and else is the first statement immediately following. This happens for the second, innermost if (see rule below) and then for the first if.

How Java selects which else to use is discussed in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5). In particular the case of a dangling else (where there are two if's and one else), which  is resolved as follows:

> The Java programming language, like C and C++ and many programming
>   languages before them, arbitrarily decrees that an else clause belongs
>   to the innermost if to which it might possibly belong.

Of course, your example is why you should just add the curly brackets (and indentation) with every if statement because then this is much clearer.

### Reachability

In your example, it is impossible to reach the "20 IF" statement, because it would require V to be both smaller than 10 and larger than 20. While Java does have some unreachable code, this is not an optimization for all possible unreachable conditions. The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) shows which checks are done.

There are quite a few rules, but for control statements, they only look if expressions are effectively constants (always true or false). For if statements this check is not even done so they can be used to disable a bit of code:

> This approach would be consistent with the treatment of other control
>   structures. However, in order to allow the if statement to be used
>   conveniently for "conditional compilation" purposes, the actual rules
>   differ.

Answer (score 8):

works like this, if v is lower than 10 you should get the print 10 else

```
public static void testIf(int v){
   if (v < 10) {  
       if (v >20 ) {  
           System.out.println(" 20 IF");
       } else {      
           System.out.println(" 20 ELSE");
       }
   } else {       
       System.out.println("10 Else");
   }
}
```

Edit: Without any braces it would look like this; not sure how to format this so bear with me...

```
public static void testIf(int v){
   if (v < 10)
       if (v >20 ) System.out.println(" 20 IF");
       else System.out.println(" 20 ELSE");
   else System.out.println("10 Else");
}
```

Comment: brackets are beautiful

Comment: @scarywombat brackets *and* indentation.

Answer (score 3):

> Normally every IF should be linked with the closest ELSE, why the last else is not a dangling ELSE? Moreover with what IF is linked.

If you well format your code it makes more sense.

```
if (v < 10)

            if (v > 20)
                System.out.println(" 20 IF");
            else
                System.out.println(" 20 ELSE");

 else
     System.out.println("10 Else");
```

It is perfectly alright. Because when you do not have `{}` only one line of code bind to the scope if `if`. However in your case, the next line after if is another `if` hence the scope is still alive.

However the logic doesn't really look good. But the code still executes fine.

As others pointed out, to keep the world happy always prefer to use `{}`.

> The last ELSE is not reachable, why it's allowed?

It is reachable if your `v` value `>= 10`

Answer (score 1):

Without curly braces, an `if` can take a single statement - in this case, an if-else. So the first `else` matches the inner `if`, and the second `else` matches the outer `if`. Adding curly braces and properly indenting the code makes it much easier to understand:

```
if (v < 10) {
    if (v >20) {
        System.out.println(" 20 IF");
    } else {
        System.out.println(" 20 ELSE");
    }
else {
    System.out.println("10 Else");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the 2nd `else` belongs to the 1st `if` , and 2nd `if` and 1st `else` belongs to the 1st `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Your middle if-else block

```
if (v >20 )  
    System.out.println(" 20 IF");
else        
    System.out.println(" 20 ELSE");
```

is considered by java as an inner block of outer if. I mean your code compiles as:

```
if (v < 10){ 
    if (v >20 )  
        System.out.println(" 20 IF");
    else        
        System.out.println(" 20 ELSE");
}
else        
    System.out.println("10 Else");
```

Answer (score 1):

A good practise is to use curly braces. {}

So your code looks like this.

```
public static void testIf(int v) {

    if (v < 10) {
        //This will actually never be true, since v cannot be both less than 
        //10 and at the same time greater than 20.   
        if (v >20 ) {  
            System.out.println(" 20 IF");
        }
        else {        
            System.out.println(" 20 ELSE");
        }
    }

    else {       
        System.out.println("10 Else");
    }
}
```

This means that following calls will print out this:

```
> testIf(9); -> //20 ELSE 
> testIf(12); -> //10 ELSE 
> testIf(23); -> //10 ELSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Last else statement will not be reachable because if and else statements are two different statements. So if you dont give the curly braces, the code will be treated as-

```
 if(v<10)
   {
     if(v>20)
        System.out.println("20 IF");
   }
 // now the following else statement will be of ""if(v<10)"" and not 
 //                                                     ""if(v>20)""
 else
   {
      System.out.println("20 ELSE");  // its not of (20 ELSE)
   }
```

Any following else statement without preceding if statement will give an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use correct indentation and brackets then how about:

```
    if (v < 10) if (v > 20) System.out.println(" 20 IF"); else System.out.println(" 20 ELSE"); else System.out.println("10 Else");
```